# Overriding iOS Settings UI - Apple rules

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

As in many apps, also in my app I have a "Settings" view.

I would like to add an item composed by text + UISwitch in order to give user possibility to change the "location services" permissions: when switch is enabled "allow location services: always", when is disabled "allow location services: never".

Question is: could this a reason for an Apple App Rejection?

I read all guidelines but I can't find an answer to my question.

Links
[Review rejections](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/).
[Review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).
[UI Tips](https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/).

Comment: It might depend on your code, can you post some lines about this UISwitch?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of app store review, what you're thinking of doing isn't technically possible. Your app can only *request* location permissions, it can't then tell the system that it doesn't need them any more.

For the user to amend location permissions they have to open the iOS settings app and go to the page for your app. You can provide a link from within your app to do this, using the `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` constant to build and open a URL.

Comment: of course, when user interact with switch item, I present  popup with  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Comment: And what do you do when they turn it off?

Comment: Damn.. I was totally center on "political-direction" of the question.. can't I present again "requestWhenInUseAuthorization()" popup?

Comment: no, you can only ask once - if the user has granted permissions the dialog isn't shown. If they've gone to settings and turned it off, I don't think you can even ask again - they have to go back to settings, otherwise you could just keep spamming them with requests

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code so I'll try to help you writing a few lines to follow to understand Apple reject.

So the first thing you need to do is to add one or both of the following keys to your Info.plist file:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Next you need to request authorization for the corresponding location method, WhenInUse or Background. Use one of these calls:

```
requestWhenInUseAuthorization
requestAlwaysAuthorization
```

Location types that you need Always authorization to use:

- Significant Location Change
- Boundary Crossing (Geofences)
- Background Location Updates (e.g. Fitness, Navigation apps) iBeacons
- Visited Locations (iOS 8+)
- Deferred Location Updates

Comment: I've already configured plist. My question is more "political" than technical

Comment: Your rejection is probably due to a breach of the standard permits (authorizations) or from a wrong use of GPS tracking but without code It's hard to say that.